# How to find the associated pipeline in Azure DevOps from a given yaml file?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have many pipelines in Azure DevOps.  My code is stored in an Azure DevOps git repository.  I know the path to a yaml file which is the definition of one of my pipelines.  Unfortunately, the naming convention of the pipelines has not always been ideal, so I cannot easily find *which* pipeline it is associated with.  Are there any quick ways to find it?  Checking each pipeline individually is not desirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No built-in feature, I write a sample python code to achieve your requirement:

```
import requests

orgname = "<Your Organization Name>"
projectname = "<Your Project Name>"
yamlname = "<Your YAML file name>"
reponame = "<Your Repo Name>"

PAT = "<Your Personal Access Token>"

url_repo = "https://dev.azure.com/"+orgname+"/"+projectname+"/_apis/git/repositories/"+reponame+"?api-version=4.1"

payload_repo={}
headers_repo = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic '+PAT
}

response_repo = requests.request("GET", url_repo, headers=headers_repo, data=payload_repo)
data_repo = response_repo.json()
repoid = data_repo.get('id')

url_pipelines = "https://dev.azure.com/"+orgname+"/"+projectname+"/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0-preview.1"

payload_pipelines={}
headers_pipelines = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic '+PAT  
}

response_pipelines = requests.request("GET", url_pipelines, headers=headers_pipelines, data=payload_pipelines)
data_pipelines = response_pipelines.json()
counter_pipelines = str(data_pipelines.get('count'))


counter = 0

for f in data_pipelines.get('value'):
    counter = counter + 1
    url_pipeline = f.get('url')
    id_pipeline = f.get('id')
    pipeline_name_current = f.get('name')
    url_pipeline = "https://dev.azure.com/"+orgname+"/"+projectname+"/_apis/pipelines/"+str(id_pipeline)+"?revision=1"

    payload_pe={}
    headers_pe = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+PAT
    }

    response_pe = requests.request("GET", url_pipeline, headers=headers_pe, data=payload_pe)
    data_pe = response_pe.json()
    if (data_pe.get('configuration').get('type') == 'yaml') and (data_pe.get('configuration').get('repository') != None):
        #
        current_yamlname = data_pe.get('configuration').get('path')
        current_pipelinename = data_pe.get('name')
        current_repoid = data_pe.get('configuration').get('repository').get('id')
        if (current_yamlname == yamlname) and (current_repoid==repoid):
            print(data_pe.get('name'))
    elif data_pe.get('configuration').get('repository'):
        print("This is not a DevOps Repository")
    else:
        #No YAML
        pass
print(counter)
```

I can get the pipeline name by providing the YAML file and repo name:

[image]

Comment: At least it is possible to access the information via the API, but I admit, I was hoping to avoid having to write such a script.